# Como adicionar background em uma lista inline ? E como remover o efeito underline padrão?

Tags: html, css, html5

Eu gostaria de adicionar um background nesse menu, como posso fazer isso?

O background-color só adiciona cor as palavras e não ao todo. E também tem esse efeito underline na lista `<nav>` que eu gostaria de remover.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> CÓDIGO DO HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aprendendohtml</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <!--<img src="_img/logo.png" alt="Programador" id="logo">-->
        <nav id="menu">
        <p id="letreiro">MarceloSantos.com</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a  href="#inicio">ÍNICIO</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#portfolio">PORTFÓLIO</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#redes-sociais">REDES SOCIAIS</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        </header>

        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Código CSS:

```
body {

}
#letreiro {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    color: #BEBEBE;
    padding: 20px;

}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 100;
    margin-right: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu é um `id` que referência um objeto no documento então você precisa usar o *sharp* "#" na frente da marcação:

```
#menu ul li {propriedades}
```

Se caso a referência fosse para uma classe o ponto vem a frente:

```
.classe{propriedades}
```

Answer (score 0):

para remover o underline de um texto basta no seu css usar:

```
 #letreiro li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 }
```

espero ter ajudado =D.